# Cannot compile simple Qt App to link against windows user32 lib

Tags: windows, qt

I have a simple QWidgets app with only one button. Here is the header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Windows.h"
//#include "Winuser.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool changed;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And the implementation

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    changed = false;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if (!changed){
//        DEVMODE *dm = new DEVMODE();
//        EnumDisplaySettings(NULL,ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS,dm);
//        dm->dmPelsWidth = (unsigned long) 1024;
//        dm->dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long) 768;
//        ChangeDisplaySettings(dm,CDS_FULLSCREEN);
        DEVMODE desiredMode = { 0 };
        desiredMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
        desiredMode.dmPelsWidth = 1024;
        desiredMode.dmPelsHeight = 768;
        desiredMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH;
        LONG res = ChangeDisplaySettings(&desiredMode,CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_GLOBAL | CDS_RESET );
    }
    else{
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL,0);
    }

    changed = !changed;
}
```

And my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ChangeResolution
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

LIBS += -luser32

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

I need to devlop an app that needs to change the resolution of the display, only when certain images are shown, to 1024x768 and then go back to normal. In order to test how to do this, I'm trying the code above I've found right here or SO. However I get the following link error when trying to compile the above code:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChangeDisplaySettingsW referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
```

From what I've researched this seems to be realated to the compiler not finding the lib, which is why I've added the LIBS line to the .pro file, but nothing changed.

My projects settings indicate that I'm using Qt 5.10.0 MSVC2017 64 bit compiler.

Any help on how to get this to compile?

Comment: Why is your Winuser.h commented ?
LNK 2019 equals to:The linker could not find a definition for external symbol "symbol" used in function "function".
Have you tried to uncomment winuser.h into your .h file ?

Comment: Your code is correct. How did you configure MSVC2017 Kit? can you invoke the command line for that kit and check your path contains your kits? something like "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x64`"  ...?